# Send data from list in SharePoint in Microsoft 365 to external API

Tags: api, sharepoint, http-post, sharepoint-online

I have a list in "SharePoint in Microsoft 365" and am looking to extend its usefulness. I would like to create a button or something that can take a row of data and send it to an external site via API (another tool that we have created).

To be clear:

- SharePoint initiates a GET or POST request
- the request must have row or field data attached
- the destination is outside of Microsoft/SharePoint

Can it be done?

(Apologies if this is a repeat question, I could only find answers that pertained to older versions of SharePoint and focused on hitting external APIs to *retrieve* data, not send it.)

Answer (score 0):

OK, i think the best choice to send Data from a selected row, is to use the [ListView Command Set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-cmdset-with-dialog-api) here you can do anything with [@pnp/nodejs](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/nodejs/).

Otherwise...

PowerAutomate can help send data.